# Load UIView Dynamically from several dll files

Tags: c#, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, dynamic-loading

I have a Navigation controller in my project. now I want to load views from different dll files, and add them into the Navigation Controller. I am not sure it is possible or not. If possible how could I do this? how could I create the separate dll for each View?

Please note that I am using Monotouch and C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a MonoTouch Library project and create your UIViews there using code (not with interface builder, it will not work)

Then, from an other project, add a reference to the library you created and add the views to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), facilitated by an [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework which [supports Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619564/ioc-library-compatible-with-monotouch).